# How can I clear one of pickerView from two?

Tags: swift, uipickerview, uipickerviewdatasource, uipickerviewdelegate

I'v got two pickerViews and when user select first after the second pickerView is  loading. But if user does it again this action, all datas appending to second pickerView. I have to clear second pickerView content when user select first one. I am using reloadAllComponents() method but it is not worked.

My Code;

```
    var country_array = [String]()
    var countryIds_array = [String]()
    var city_array = [String]()
    var cityIds_array = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        getCountry()
    }

func getCountry(){
        //var hata = false
        print("Getting Country List")
        let query = PFQuery(className: "cls_ulke")
        query.limit = 300
        query.order(byDescending: "oncelik")
        query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects: [PFObject]?, error) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                print("Getted!")
                print("Looping------------------>")
                if let objects = objects {
                    for object in objects{
                        print(object.objectId ?? "BOŞ")
                        print(object["ulke_adi"])
                        self.country_array.append(object["ulke_adi"] as! String)
                        self.countryIds_array.append(object.objectId!)
                    }
                    self.pckerview.delegate = self
                    self.pckerview.dataSource = self
                }
                print("<-------------------Looped")
            }else{
                print("HATA")
            }
        }
    }

    func getCities(objectID:String){
        print("Getting City List")
        let query = PFQuery(className: "cls_il")
        query.limit = 1000
        query.order(byDescending: "oncelik")
        query.whereKey("ulke_ID", equalTo: PFObject(withoutDataWithClassName: "cls_ulke", objectId: objectID))
        query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects:[PFObject]?, error) in
            if error == nil {
                print("Getted!")
                print("Looping------------------>")
                if let objects = objects {
                    for object in objects {
                        print(object["il_adi"])
                        self.city_array.append(object["il_adi"] as! String)
                        self.cityIds_array.append(object.objectId!)
                    }
                    self.pckerview2.reloadAllComponents()
                    self.pckerview2.delegate = self
                    self.pckerview2.dataSource = self
                }
                print("<-------------------Looped")
            }else{
                print("HATA")
            }
        }
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        var donecek = 0
        if pickerView == pckerview {
            donecek = country_array.count
        }else if pickerView == pckerview2{
            donecek = city_array.count
        }
        return donecek
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        var donecek = ""
        if pickerView == pckerview {
            donecek = country_array[row]
        }else if pickerView == pckerview2{
            donecek = city_array[row]
        }
        return donecek
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        if pickerView == pckerview {
            tfield.text = countryIds_array[row]
            getCities(objectID:countryIds_array[row])

        }
    }
```

Comment: maybe a better idea would be to add a second component to your main pickerView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `reloadAllComponents()` is calling your delegate for a reload. From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipickerview/1614380-reloadallcomponents):

> Calling this method causes the picker view to query the delegate for new data for all components.

However, your code show that you are only setting the `pckerview2.delegate` after it.

```
self.pckerview2.reloadAllComponents()
self.pckerview2.delegate = self
self.pckerview2.dataSource = self
```

So my guess is that the `reloadAllCompontents()` did not manage to query the delegate as it is `nil`.(Unless you have set it in other place) Try moving it below like this:

```
self.pckerview2.delegate = self
self.pckerview2.dataSource = self 
self.pckerview2.reloadAllComponents()
```

The 2nd possibilities is that you did not clear the `city_array` therefore you are always appending city to it. If that is the case, before the `for` loops just add a `removeAll()`. Something like this:

```
print("Looping------------------>")
    if let objects = objects {
        self.city_array.removeAll()
        self.cityIds_array.removeAll()

        for object in objects {
        // rest of the codes
```

Comment: @EmreErol looking at it again, it seems like you did not clear your array. Did you clear the array before appending new item again? Look at my edited answer.